# how to set com.apple.security.smartcard entitlement to yes in application

Tags: c++, macos, smartcard

I am trying to build an application to deal with smart card on mac but when I try to use the defaultManager of TKSmartCardSlotManager to read the smart card it returns as nil because the com.apple.secuirty.smartcard entitlement is not set to true that what I read in the mac TKSmartCard.h file in the comments but I am so new in dealing with mac and don't know how to set it to true through the calling application.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** 
what I tried so far is creating a property list file and adding it to the project then building it with the project but still it seems it doesn't add the required entitlement. this is the file I add :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
       <key>com.apple.security.smartcard</key>
       <true/>
  </dict>

</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply writing a .entitlements file contains the following :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.smartcard</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Then add my project.entitlements to code signing entitlements in Xcode build settings.