# TKSmartCardSlotManager iOS

Tags: ios, cryptotokenkit

I'm trying to access TKSmartCardSlotManager from my iOS app. Calling `TKSmartCardSlotManager.default` always returns `nil`. I've set the `com.apple.security.smartcard` entitlement to `yes`, but no luck. The console logs an

> The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.ctkd.slot-client
> was invalidated

error, which seems like an authorization issue to me?!

Has anybody got this working?

Comment: This method returns nil unless the com.apple.security.smartcard entitlement is enabled.  iOS 13.0+ Double check :) strange..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920976/how-to-set-com-apple-security-smartcard-entitlement-to-yes-in-application take a look here

Comment: @SiarheiYakushevich Do you have this working in an iOS project? I tried your solution but still no luck